# Custom date-type to Date

Tags: json, angular

I am getting my date from my API in following json format:

```json
"mydate":{"year":2023,"month":2,"day":1}
```

I tried to use in template like this:

```html
<td>{{ mydate | date }}</td>
```

Which is giving me error.

> Unable to convert "[object Object]" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe

How can I show my date as `Jan 2, 2023`  Format?

Answer (score 0):

Make a Pipe which converts your format to `Date`.
See this doc: [Making custom pipe Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#creating-pipes-for-custom-data-transformations)

After that you can change your template to something like this:

```html
<td>{{ mydate | appToDate | date }}</td>
```